# Radon measure as the derivative of a BV function

Tags: measure-theory, bounded-variation

It is known that if $f$ is a function of bounded variation in a set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, its distributional derivative can be representated by a finite Radon measure in $\Omega$.

My question is: given any Radon measure in $\Omega$, is it always possible to find a BV function whose distributional derivative is the given Radon measure?

Comment: In $1$ dimension, yes, these are just the functions $\int_0^x \mu(\mathrm{d}x) + C$. When $n>1$, then some functions are not in general gradients (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field)

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Now it is clear to me.